# How to transform a table based on certain conditions on columns in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to make a table from an existing table in which `t1-t6` columns are specified by `0` and `1` means `No` and `Yes`. `mR` is a score assigned for every bin. The first two columns are `chromosome` and `bin start`. This is a small sample dataset; the original file has over 5 million rows.

```
   chr   start    t1    t2    t3    t4    t5    t6    mR
   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  chr1      0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
2  chr1    100     1     1     0     0     0     0     2.04
3  chr1    200     0     0     1     1     0     0     3.20
4  chr1    300     0     0     1     0     1     0     2.76
5  chr1    400     0     1     0     1     0     0     3.44
6  chr1    500     0     0     1     0     1     0     2.12
7  chr1    600     1     1     0     0     0     0     1.40
8  chr1    700     1     1     0     0     0     0     1.93
9  chr1    800     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
10 chr1    900     1     0     0     1     1     0     5.40
11 chr1    1000    0     1     1     0     0     0     2.65
```

Now, I want create another table where,
the `mR` values will be averaged if any redundant patterns are seen between columns `t1` and `t6`. For instance, in this above Table, `bin 4` and `bin 6` have similar pattern (`t3 =1`, `t5 =1`), thus cumulative `mR` will be `(2.76+2.12)/2 = 2.44` and corresponding chromosome location will be added accordingly in a new column.

```
    chr   start    t1    t2    t3    t4    t5    t6    mR    CmR    Location
   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <chr>    
1  chr1      0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0       0
2  chr1    100     1     1     0     0     0     0     2.04    NA
3  chr1    200     0     0     1     1     0     0     3.20    3.20
4  chr1    300     0     0     1     0     1     0     2.76    NA
5  chr1    400     0     1     0     1     0     0     3.44    3.44
6  chr1    500     0     0     1     0     1     0     2.12    2.44    chr1-300,chr1-500
7  chr1    600     1     1     0     0     0     0     1.40    NA
8  chr1    700     1     1     0     0     0     0     1.93    1.79    chr1-100,chr1-600,chr1-700
9  chr1    800     0     0     0     0     0     0     0       0
10 chr1    900     1     0     0     1     1     0     5.40    5.40
11 chr1    1000    0     1     1     0     0     0     2.65    2.65
```

Please let me know, if I'm able to convey my message.

What I got after implementing @benson23's approach for the large data set. It works well with a small dataset, but not for a large dataset. When `mR` is `0` the `CmR` should be `0` and when `mR` has some value other than `0` it should be reflected on `CmR`.

```
SAM_bc01f[95:103,]
# A tibble: 9 × 11
  chr   start    t1    t2    t3    t4    t5    t6    mR   CmR Location
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   
1 chr1   9400     0     0     0     0     0     0  0     3.64 NA      
2 chr1   9500     0     0     0     0     0     0  0     3.64 NA      
3 chr1   9600     0     0     0     0     0     0  0     3.64 NA      
4 chr1   9700     0     0     0     0     0     0  0     3.64 NA      
5 chr1   9800     0     0     0     0     0     0  0     3.64 NA      
6 chr1   9900     0     0     0     0     0     0  0.16 NA    NA      
7 chr1  24600     0     0     0     1     0     0  5.92 NA    NA      
8 chr1  24700     0     0     0     1     0     0  4.44 NA    NA      
9 chr1  26900     0     1     0     0     0     0  1.64 NA    NA
```

Also, it appears that the start locations seem to have duplicated from the previous chromosome location when the chromosome number changed.

````
[1] NA
[2] "chr1-214747600,chr1-220003800,chr2-214747600,chr2-220003800"
[3] "chr1-224595000,chr2-224595000" 
[4] "chr1-191887000,chr2-191887000,chr3-191887000"
[5] "chr1-180010900,chr1-207226200,chr2-180010900,chr2-207226200,chr3-180010900,chr4-180010900,chr5-180010900"
[6] "chr1-163682300,chr2-163682300,chr3-163682300,chr4-163682300,chr5-163682300,chr6-163682300" ```
````